# Powershell large hex range

Tags: powershell, hex, large-data, largenumber

I am trying to make a range of hex from a000000000-afffffffff, but the values are too large for Int32. Getting error `Cannot convert value "687194767360" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32."`

Here is the code
`(0xa000000000..0xafffffffff|% ToString X10).ToLower()`

Comment: As an aside: if you use `x10` instead of `X10`, you'll get lowercase hex digits directly, so you won't need `.ToLower()`.

Comment: To do what with?

Comment: `if ($i -gt 0xa000000000 -and $i -lt 0xafffffffff) { 'whatever' }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The endpoints of `..`, the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-),  must fit into `[int]` values, which your numbers exceed.

- Additionally, since you're trying to collect the output of the streaming `0xa000000000..0xafffffffff| % ToString X10` pipeline command *in memory in full*, by enclosing it in `(...)` and calling method `.ToString()` on it, the collected outputs would have to fit into an *array*, and the count of elements in your range exceed the max. capacity of a [.NET array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Array) too.

Similarly, the [`[Linq.Enumerable]::Range()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Linq.Enumerable.Range) method unfortunately also only accepts `[int]` endpoints.

However, you can **implement a (custom) *streaming* solution**, where PowerShell creates and emits each formatted number (string) to the pipeline *one by one*:

```
$num = 0xa000000000
while ($num -le 0xafffffffff) { ($num++).ToString('x10') }
```

Note:

- While this works, it will be *slow*.
- **You won't be able to capture the result *as a whole* in a collection *in memory***.

  - If you were to stream the output to a *file* unfiltered, you'd end up with a file 704 GB(!) / 768 GB(!) in size on Unix-like platforms / Windows.
  - In-memory, partitioning the output into chunk(s) small enough to fit into array(s) is the only option.

Comment: I was afraid of this being too large to handle. and yeah 768 gb (plus what else i need to tack on) wont work. Well another side project bites the dust. Thanks for the education

Answer (score 2):

Not possible to hold the collection as a whole using `System.Array`:

> The array size is limited to a total of 4 billion elements, and to a maximum index of 0X7FEFFFFF in any given dimension (0X7FFFFFC7 for byte arrays and arrays of single-byte structures).

Nor using `List<T>`:

> .NET Framework only: For very large List objects, you can increase the maximum capacity to 2 billion elements on a 64-bit system by setting the enabled attribute of the  configuration element to true in the run-time environment.

Assuming you have enough memory to hold **68,719,476,735 elements** which I don't think you do :), you could do a list of lists:

```
$hex = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
$tmp = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()

for($i = 0xa000000000; $i -le 0xafffffffff; $i++) {
    if($tmp.Count -eq [int]::MaxValue) {
        $hex.Add($tmp)
        $tmp.Clear()
    }
    $tmp.Add($i.ToString('x10'))
}
```

You can use `$i.ToString('x10')` or `'{0:x10}' -f $i` to produce lower-case hex. See [**Hexadecimal format specifier (X)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#hexadecimal-format-specifier-x) for details.

Comment: @Theo good point, thanks Theo

Comment: Does this... work? The range described is _larger_ than `[int]::MaxValue`; I'd expect you either run out of memory, or receive an error after the operation is over because the output can't fit into a 1-dimensional array.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I don't know, I don't have enough RAM for this

Comment: I do (it just took a while to allocate enough ^_^), and PowerShell indeed throws an `[OutOfMemoryException]` with the message "Array dimensions exceeded supported range." :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen clearly will not work, exceeds `System.Array` limit :D (4 billion)